# Mixin config files from s3 bucket when building app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I've created a pipeline sourcing the app from GitHub. In the build step the app is built - and all that works fine.

However the deployment requires some other files to exist within the built app (specifically Docker and Beanstalk related config files).

What I want to do is to, during the post build step, grab these files from a S3 bucket (other than the target bucket that will hold the finished artifact).

```
build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp s3://[***config-bucket-id***]/test.txt test.txt
```

I am however running in to permissions problem, since the config bucket is not public. Also it seems that when I manually run the pipeline it runs as my own user, but with an assumed role.

1. It it possible to tell codebuild to always run as a specific user with a specific role?
2. How to I define a S3 bucket policy with a Principal statement that targets a role rather than a user?

---

I run the `aws sts get-caller-identity` in the build process to see who's executing the build, and it gives me

```
{
    "UserId": "[some-id]:AWSCodeBuild-[hash-that-differs-for-each-build]",
    "Account": "[my-account-id]",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::[my-account-id]:assumed-role/codebuild-[...]-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-[hash-that-differs-for-each-build]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need an IAM-role for codebuild.I recommend to configure codebuild and the s3 to work with this role.
See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control.html